# How can I go about sharing information about a potential opportunity for musicians here

Tags: discussion

Don't get me wrong, I'm not going for something like promoting an online music group.

But if there an opportunity at an online music group (no money involved anywhere) which I think people here at Music.SE might be able to utilize, How exactly should I go about telling people this? Is there space for this or Music Stack Exchange isn't the place for this?

Like for example, this online orchestra planning to perform 'Concerto de Aranjeuz' and I wish to share this opportunity with guitarists here so they might be able to use it

Sorry if there is no space for this in Music Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can post these kind of advertisements (because it *is* an advertisement, even if it might be relevant to Music.SE) on your [profile](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile); see [How much advertising is allowed on userinfo pages?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31448/295232) This case would fall well within the rules.

Other than that, I've seen people posting advertisements in similar spirit (but about different topics) in [chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=music.stackexchange.com). I'm not familiar with the culture of The Practice Room, the main chatroom of this site, but perhaps you can ask one of the regulars.

Answer (score 3):

For community promotion there is always our [list, refreshed every year](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3476/104), which chooses the advertisements our page gets.

The upvoted ones are included in a rotation in the sidebar on visits to Music.SE.

They are most relevant for groups or community interests that are of continuous interest, rather than a single event.